# How do I create a formatted .txt file from an existing one?

Tags: c

I want to make a program that reads an existing .txt file, formats it to only have X characters per line (or less if a word is broken in the process) and saves it with a different name.

I can get it to "break" at the 10th char, however i can't get the part of not breaking words...

Here is the my code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#define NCARACTERES 10

int fFormatar(){
    FILE *fp=NULL;
    char frase[50], *res=NULL;
    int i;

    fp=fopen("texto.txt","r");

    if(fp==NULL){
        printf("ERRO AO ABRIR");
        return -1;
    }
    while(!feof(fp)){
        res=fgets(frase, NCARACTERES, fp);
        if (res){
        printf("%s\n", res);
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;   
}

//MAIN
int main() {

    fFormatar(); 

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: That doesn't look like C#, it looks more like C/C++. Have you maybe choosen the wrong tag by accident?

Comment: It would help to show the contents of `texto.txt` as well as the expected result and the result that is output from your program.

Comment: You need to think about how the computer should solve the problem. Then you need to tell the computer how to solve the problem. Is there a specific part which you need help with? Do you have no idea how the computer should solve the problem, or do you have an idea but not know how to write it in C?

Comment: I think the best approach would be to read a complete line and check if the `10th` and `11th` characters are both non whitespace, that way you know that there is a word  that doesn't fit in the line, then you can go back until the first whitespace and write everything from the beginning until then, you can do this recursively moving the starting char of the line. Then it's just a matter of  reading the next line when the first one is done and repeat the process.

Comment: @bassfader, you are absolutely correct! My bad...

Comment: @J... texto.txt could be anything, the user puts it into the folder and the program formats it in a way that a single line only has 10 or less characters.

Comment: @user253751 my inicial idea was to make the code break every 11th letter, and if it was a blank space it will go back until it found a letter, in wich it will create a new line...however, i could not figure it out how to write that

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be OK with reading and writing files, so I'll show how to split strings on spaces.

```
MyOutput (char* Line, int Length, BOOL AddBreak); //Your preferred output to either screen or file. Should print Length characters from string Line, and add "\r", "\n" or "\r\n" if needed.

void RecursiveSplit (char* P, int MaxLen)
{
  int SpacePos; //Nearest space
  if (strlen(P) <= MaxLen || P[MaxLen]=='\r' || P[MaxLen]=='\n') //Nothing to do: it already fits into the line.
  {
    MyOutput (P, strlen(P), FALSE); //Printing the line without CR/LF (it already have them)
    return;
  }
  for (SpacePos=MaxLen; SpacePos>0; SpacePos--) if (P[SpacePos] == ' ') break; //Finding the space after the rightmost word which still fits in the line
  if (!SpacePos) SpacePos=MaxLen; //No spaces found! We can only break the long word. The task have no solution (but we must not crash or freeze either way)
  MyOutput (P, SpacePos, TRUE); //Printing the line before the space position, add CR/LF after it;
  while (P[SpacePos] == ' ') SpacePos++;  //Don't begin the next line with spaces! Find the next word first.
  if (P[SpacePos] != 0 && P[SpacePos] != '\r' && P[SpacePos] != '\n') //Line may end with multiple spaces, we should not print them.
    RecursiveSplit (P+SpacePos, MaxLen); //If there's a word after those spaces (not the end of a line), we must recursively call the function for the remaining characters.
}
```

Comment: For reference (just because learners are presumably reading this answer) - this is very un-idiomatic C code. `CamelCase` local variable names are weird, using the same `CaseStyle` for for variables and functions is not recommended, I don't know where `BOOL`, `TRUE` and `FALSE` come from but they're not standard, and you're using C++ comments in C code.

Answer (score 0):

To get an idea of how many little complexities apply to this, take a look at the documentation for the (freely-available) [GNU fmt](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/fmt-invocation.html)

> By default, blank lines, spaces between words, and indentation are preserved in the output; successive input lines with different indentation are not joined; tabs are expanded on input and introduced on output.
>
> fmt prefers breaking lines at the end of a sentence, and tries to avoid line breaks after the first word of a sentence or before the last word of a sentence.

Even the simplest thing you can *possibly* do gets rapidly more complex:

1. read the max number of characters you want on a line (call it **N**)
2. is the last character whitespace (use [`isspace`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isspace) to check)?

   1. **yes** - simplest case: output the first **N**-1 characters, followed by newline, and loop back to **1**.
   2. **no** - walk backwards until we find whitespace. Do we find it?

      1. **yes** - OK, so **2.1** was just the degenerate case of this. We behave the same, except that now we need to save the last part of the line (after the whitespace where we are going to split) to reuse when we go back to **1**. So, that step is now a bit more complex as well.
      2. **no** - we have **N** consecutive non-whitespace characters. You need some policy to handle it; the simplest is to just give up and output all **N** characters followed by a newline.

Note that this will still do a much worse job than just using `fmt` mentioned above. Which is open-source, so you can read its code if you want.